# Can't install Apache Apollo -- Can't find "keytool"

Tags: apache, centos, keytool, apollo

I'm trying to install Apache Apollo on CentOS, and I get the following:

```
sudo ${APOLLO_HOME}/bin/apollo create mybroker

Creating apollo instance at: mybroker
Generating ssl keystore...
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "keytool" (in directory "mybroker/etc"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I added keytool to my path, I can run keytool from the command line, but for some reason the Apollo installation can't find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had installed java and used alternatives to create a symbolic link. When I tried to create an Apollo instance, I got the same error message as you. Apparently the Apollo install expects keytool to be available in your search path.

I added a symbolic link for keytool, removed the previous aborted instance, and then the Apollo instance creation completed successfully.

In my case, the alternatives command was:

```
sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/keytool keytool /opt/jre1.8.0_51/bin/keytool 1
```

This assumes you want to put the link in /usr/bin. And of course the second path argument needs to match where you've put the Java install.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with CentOS 6.5 64bit.
The solution was to download and install jdk-7u65-linux-x64.rpm and then run:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_65 <br>
 export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

While creating broker, you are generating ssl keystore. For that a program "keytool" should be available.

"keytool" is part of every java installation, so you should try to install java. Anyway, to run apollo you are going to need it.